# How to convert a 2D matrix into a graph object in R

Tags: r, graphs

```
set.seed(42)
iris_matrix <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])
image(iris_matrix)
g<-cor(iris_matrix)
g
library(igraph)
independent.vertex.sets(g, min=NULL, max=NULL)
```

Error

Error in independent.vertex.sets(g, min = NULL, max = NULL) : 
       Not a graph object

Trying to find independent sets but problems in converting the correlation  matrix into a graph object.

Comment: [this might help](http://igraph.org/r/doc/aaa-igraph-package.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to **convert your matrix into a graph**.
For example, started from your "g" :

```
G <- as.undirected(graph.adjacency(g, weighted = T))
plot(G, edge.color=c("red","green")[sign(E(G)$weight)/2 + 1.5], 
     edge.width = 3 *abs(E(G)$weight))
```

Comment: Could you please explain the [sign(E(G)$weight)/2 + 1.5] part? @jean lescut

Comment: Another thing is I want an edge to appear only when the value in the adjacency matrix is beyond a particular threshold. Please Help.